# Sort is not working on react table, I am using @Ashvin27/react-datatable package

Tags: reactjs, sorting

I am using this table package

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ashvin27/react-datatable

Note: Everything is working, even the "All" sort is working on the first page but,

When selecting page two and selecting "all" sort data is blank,

I am expecting results in second page with all sort